# How to find missing records from one table compared to another table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table called CalTest which has a TransDate Field and an ID Field. I also have a standard Calendar table with dates from 2000 to 2020.
In my CalTest table I have

```
ID          TransDate
1            4/1/2015
2            4/2/2015
3            4/4/2015
4            4/6/2015
```

I need to run a query where the results will be

```
Transdate
4/3/2015
4/5/2015
```

if I run this:

```
select t1.CalendarDate
FROM Calendar t1
left join Caltest t2 ON t2.TRANSDATE = t1.CalendarDate
where (t2.TRANSDATE IS not NULL)
```

I get:

```
TransDate
4/1/2015
4/2/2015
4/4/2015
4/6/2015
```

If I run this:

```
select t1.CalendarDate
FROM Calendar t1
left join Caltest t2 ON t2.TRANSDATE = t1.CalendarDate
where (t2.TRANSDATE IS NULL)
```

I get all the calendarDates from the Calendar table except for:

```
4/1/2015
4/2/2015
4/4/2015
4/6/2015
```

And if I run:

```
select t1.Transdate
FROM Caltest t1
left join Calendar t2 ON t2.CalendarDate = t1.TRANSDATE
where (t2.CalendarDate IS NULL)
```

I get no results back.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the calendar table as base since you want to find missing dates.

```
SELECT c.CalendarDate 
FROM Calendar c
LEFT OUTER JOIN Caltest t
   ON c.CalendarDate  =  t.TRANSDATE
WHERE c.CalendarDate >= (SELECT MIN(t2.TRANSDATE) FROM Caltest t2) 
AND   c.CalendarDate <= (SELECT MAX(t2.TRANSDATE) FROM Caltest t2) 
AND   t.ID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to constrain the Calendar table to be just the time frame of the Transaction table.

```
select t1.CalendarDate
FROM Calendar t1
left join Caltest t2 ON t1.CalendarDate = t2.TRANSDATE
where (t2.TRANSDATE IS NULL) 
      and CalendarDate < getdate()
      and CalendarDate >= (select min(TransDate) from Caltest )
```

I recommend hard coding the date ranges instead of using the sub query as it is a performance problem otherwise.    I also assume you don't have transactions greater than today.

You can also create a Calendar table just for the min-max date ranges and join to that to avoid the < or >= comparisons in the query.

Answer (score -2):

Thank you all for your help.
Here is the query that worked for me:

```
    SELECT B.CalendarDate, A.TransDate
FROM Calendar AS B  
 left outer JOIN CalTest AS A ON A.TransDate = B.CalendarDate 
 where A.TransDate IS NULL and B.CalendarDate between '4/1/2015' and '4/10/2015'
 Order By b.CalendarDate
```

thanks again for your help